# Working out frequency in sql?

Tags: sql, select, frequency

I am creating a database for a library with the following four tables.

Table 1 - book

`isbn                title            author
111-2-33-444444-5   Pro JavaFX       Dave Smith
222-3-44-555555-6   Oracle Systems   Kate Roberts
333-4-55-666666-7   Expert jQuery    Mike Smith`

Table 2 - copy

`code         isbn           duration
1011    111-2-33-444444-5      21
1012    111-2-33-444444-5      14
1013    111-2-33-444444-5      7
2011    222-3-44-555555-6      21
3011    333-4-55-666666-7      7
3012    333-4-55-666666-7      14`

Table 3 - student

`no     name    school       embargo
2001    Mike      CMP          No
2002    Andy      CMP          Yes
2003    Sarah     ENG          No
2004    Karen     ENG          Yes
2005    Lucy      BUE          No`

Table 4 - loan

`code    no       taken        due        return
1011    2002    2015.01.10  2015.01.31  2015.01.31
1011    2002    2015.02.05  2015.02.26  2015.02.23
1011    2003    2015.05.10  2015.05.31

1013    2003    2014.03.02  2014.03.16  2014.03.10
1013    2002    2014.08.02  2014.08.16  2014.08.16
2011    2004    2013.02.01  2013.02.22  2013.02.20
3011    2002    2015.07.03  2015.07.10

3011    2005    2014.10.10  2014.10.17  2014.10.20`

I have been looking into working out the frequency of book loans throughout this database. I am looking for create a query that will show me the frequency of all books that have been loaned 2 or more times.

I understand that I would have to take 'code' from loan and find rows with the same code, but I am completely lost on how to work out the frequency. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have at least part of the solution, present it.